# Only logged in for one request, logged out after refresh

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having a really weird issue which I can't figure out. I'm pretty sure I miss something in the configuration, so I hope someone can help me out.

I'm trying to create a simple login form in Symfony. When I login, I see that the authenticated user is indeed the user I just tried to login with. However, when I refresh the page, or browse to a different page, the users gets logged out and I'm getting redirected back to the login page. I don't understand why I get logged out all the time.

My user class:

```
<?php namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    public $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return ['ROLE_USER'];
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My Guard Authenticator:

```
<?php namespace AppBundle\Authentication;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class Authenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator implements GuardAuthenticatorInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    private $em;

    private $encoder;


    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->encoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * Get the authentication credentials from the request and return them
     * as any type (e.g. an associate array). If you return null, authentication
     * will be skipped.
     *
     * Whatever value you return here will be passed to getUser() and checkCredentials()
     *
     * For example, for a form login, you might:
     *
     *      if ($request->request->has('_username')) {
     *          return array(
     *              'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
     *              'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
     *          );
     *      } else {
     *          return;
     *      }
     *
     * Or for an API token that's on a header, you might use:
     *
     *      return array('api_key' => $request->headers->get('X-API-TOKEN'));
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'username' => $request->request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password')
        ];
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('login');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    /**
     * Return a UserInterface object based on the credentials.
     *
     * The *credentials* are the return value from getCredentials()
     *
     * You may throw an AuthenticationException if you wish. If you return
     * null, then a UsernameNotFoundException is thrown for you.
     *
     * @param mixed                 $credentials
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     *
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     *
     * @return UserInterface|null
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $user = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            ->findOneBy(array(
                'email' => $credentials['username']));

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the credentials are valid.
     *
     * If any value other than true is returned, authentication will
     * fail. You may also throw an AuthenticationException if you wish
     * to cause authentication to fail.
     *
     * The *credentials* are the return value from getCredentials()
     *
     * @param mixed         $credentials
     * @param UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws AuthenticationException
     */
    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $plainPassword = $credentials['password'];


        if ($this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $plainPassword))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication executed, but failed (e.g. wrong username password).
     *
     * This should return the Response sent back to the user, like a
     * RedirectResponse to the login page or a 403 response.
     *
     * If you return null, the request will continue, but the user will
     * not be authenticated. This is probably not what you want to do.
     *
     * @param Request                 $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $exception
     *
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Called when authentication executed and was successful!
     *
     * This should return the Response sent back to the user, like a
     * RedirectResponse to the last page they visited.
     *
     * If you return null, the current request will continue, and the user
     * will be authenticated. This makes sense, for example, with an API.
     *
     * @param Request        $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @param string         $providerKey The provider (i.e. firewall) key
     *
     * @return Response|null
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Does this method support remember me cookies?
     *
     * Remember me cookie will be set if *all* of the following are met:
     *  A) This method returns true
     *  B) The remember_me key under your firewall is configured
     *  C) The "remember me" functionality is activated. This is usually
     *      done by having a _remember_me checkbox in your form, but
     *      can be configured by the "always_remember_me" and "remember_me_parameter"
     *      parameters under the "remember_me" firewall key
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And finally my security.yaml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        secured_area:
            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - user_authenticator

        main:
            pattern:    ^/login
            form_login: ~
            provider: our_db_provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I also checked the permissions on the sessions directory and set it to 777. I see that a new session file is created, but somehow it keeps breaking.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I also see that when I login with my credentials I get logged in anonymously. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing the Serializable interface. 
This is needed to store the user information in the session.

```
/** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt,
    ));
}

/** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        // see section on salt below
        // $this->salt
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
```

If that is not the only issue please consider following http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html
step by step

**Update:** Why do you write your own authenticator? Maybe try using the default one this could very well be also the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't fix the issue, however, when I set a "remember me" token it actually does work. From what I can see is that it is indeed a problem with the session. From the security token in the session it's not able to retrieve the user, but it is able to retrieve it from the remember me cookie. I am also writing my own authenticator because I just wan to know how this thing works :)